# Open word document in a browser not working --asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Want to open my word and PDF document in a browser window for display. Hwoever, my PDF document is opening fine but the word document fails. Below is my code.

```
public ActionResult ViewResume(long userid)
        {
            string FileName = getResumeName(userid);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/files/"), FileName);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(path,
                                     FileMode.Open,
                                     FileAccess.Read
                                   );
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(FileName);

            string extension = info.Extension;
            FileStreamResult fsResult;

            if (info.Extension == ".pdf")
                fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
            else
                fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/vnd.ms-word");

            return fsResult;
        }
```

When i try to open word document, It download a .exe file for me instead. I am not sure what the issue is. It opens PDF without an issue. Pls any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I am suspecting thE MIME type . I am not sure which is the right one for doc .

Comment: It's the mime type, Try this one instead `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: Nativly it's not supported to view a Microsoft Word document in a browser. There are a several options: Convert the Word document to PDF or use a Word Viewer for MVC. For downloading the files the answer of Alundra is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Microsoft 2007` and `2010`, here's a list for the Mime types:

---

**OpenXML formats for Microsoft Office 2007/2010 MIME types**

- Microsoft Word 2007 document (.docx)
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
- Microsoft PowerPoint 2007 presentation (.pptx)
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
- Microsoft Excel 2007 workbook (.xlsx)
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

And here's a [complete list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278%28office.12%29.aspx) from MS

EDIT:
This solution will download the file , in order to open the word document inline in your browser, there is no native support for that , for many reasons , as you will need to consider the formatting, rendering,parsing ...
You will need to implement an external library for that , here's an example  [ASP.Net Document Viewer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Document-Viewer-e7c2a39f) [GroupDocs.Viewer](http://groupdocs.com/html5-document-viewer)

Comment: That was helpful but it download the doc file instead of opening. It does open pdf though